# MFC Printing bitmap only prints in black

Tags: c++, printing, bitmap, mfc

I have the following method to print a bitmap which did work perfectly but now it prints the area of the bitmap all in black. I've tested my test app which was compiled on my PC on another PC and it prints the bitmap perfectly. I've debugged it and it is opening the bitmap file because its reading the correct dimensions. I'm at a loss to see what has happen, Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
void CTestAppPrintDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

    CString path;

    path = "Test1.bmp";
    PrintBitmap(path);
} 

void CTestAppPrintDlg::PrintBitmap(LPCTSTR filename) {
CPrintDialog printDlg(FALSE);
printDlg.GetDefaults();
  return; 
CDC dc;
if (!dc.Attach(printDlg.GetPrinterDC())) {
    AfxMessageBox(_T("No printer found!")); return;
}

dc.m_bPrinting = TRUE;
DOCINFO di;
// Initialise print document details
::ZeroMemory(&di, sizeof(DOCINFO));
di.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
di.lpszDocName = filename;
BOOL bPrintingOK = dc.StartDoc(&di); // Begin a new print job 
// Get the printing extents
// and store in the m_rectDraw field of a 
// CPrintInfo object
CPrintInfo Info;
Info.SetMaxPage(1); // just one page 
int maxw = dc.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES);
int maxh = dc.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES);
Info.m_rectDraw.SetRect(0, 0, maxw, maxh);
for (UINT page = Info.GetMinPage(); page <=
    Info.GetMaxPage() && bPrintingOK; page++) {
    dc.StartPage();    // begin new page
    Info.m_nCurPage = page;
    CBitmap bitmap;
    // LoadImage does the trick here, it creates a DIB section
    // You can also use a resource here
    // by using MAKEINTRESOURCE() ... etc. 
    if (!bitmap.Attach(::LoadImage(
        ::GetModuleHandle(NULL), filename, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
        LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE))) {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Error loading bitmap!")); return;
    }
    BITMAP bm;
    bitmap.GetBitmap(&bm);
    int w = bm.bmWidth;
    int h = bm.bmHeight;
    // create memory device context
    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    CBitmap *pBmp = memDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);
    memDC.SetMapMode(dc.GetMapMode());
    dc.SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
    // now stretchblt to maximum width on page
    dc.StretchBlt(0, 0, w, h, &memDC, 0, 0, w, h, SRCCOPY);
    // clean up
    memDC.SelectObject(pBmp);
    bPrintingOK = (dc.EndPage() > 0);   // end page
}
if (bPrintingOK)
    dc.EndDoc(); // end a print job
else dc.AbortDoc();           // abort job.
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the person who gave me a negative rating. This was very helpful!

I've found that it was nothing to do with my code and the cause was the Windows Update [KB5000802](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/march-9-2021-kb5000802-os-builds-19041-867-and-19042-867-63552d64-fe44-4132-8813-ef56d3626e14). I uninstalled this update and it now works.

Comment: It is could you got it working. But updates are designed to improve the system and make it more secure. So you might need to investigate that some more. It remind me of some of the apps that run on computers to protect against privacy issues and when you try to do screen grabs they "black out" the view. Maybe some settings on Anti Virus also do the same.

I know what you mean about negative votes. I don't see them as useful in IMHO. Constructive criticism via a comment is much better. But I guess negative votes do serve a purpose. Some questions are really poor at times. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the windows update KB5000802 has a known issue with printing and printer driver Microsoft have issued an update which corrects this https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/03/16/windows-10-kb5001567-released-to-fix-kb5000802-bsod-printing-issue/